# svn to git branch to branch syncing

Tags: git, svn

We have multiple branches under SVN repo, I have converted them to GIT using git svn clone, Now I want to work on sync part following are my SVN branches:

1. rapid
2. stage
3. production

I want to make them in sync, changes which committed on SVN **stage** branch should be synced to GIT stage branch only and similar to other branches.

I used the following command to sync but changes are not syncing to git branch:

```
git reset --soft refs/remotes/stage
git svn fetch
git push --set-upstream origin stage ( I already pushed all branches to GIT server using **git push -u origin --all** )
```

Can anyone help me to sync these branch with their svn commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute below command on converted git repository it will give you reference remote branch names:

printf "git push origin "; git show-ref | grep refs/remotes | grep -v '@' | grep -v remotes/tags | perl -ne 'print "refs/remotes/$1:refs/heads/$1 " if m!refs/remotes/(.*)!'; echo

After that use 
git push origin reference_branch_name_from_above_output.